# How to sort collection quite specifically by linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, linq-to-objects

```
var ids = new int[] { 3, 2, 20, 1 };
var entities = categories.Where(entity => ids.Contains(entity.Id));
```

I have to sort entities by exactly same like in ids array. How can i do that ?

Comment: If this is linq to objects as you have tagged, i don't see the problem. Do you mean you want to do this in [tag:LINQ-to-Entities]?

Comment: Do you really need to use LINQ for this? It's probably easier to stick with a traditional loop.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes no, another solution is acceptable

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett as you see entities are filtered by ids array but they are not sorted exactly like ids array. I use objects which is already fetched from entity framework.

Comment: @Freshblood:Ahh, i see. Looks like spender's answer is what you're after then.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick (written off the top of my head, so may have mistakes)

```
var ids = new int[] { 3, 2, 20, 1 };
var ordering = ids.Select((id,index) => new {id,index});
var entities = 
    categories
        .Where(entity => ids.Contains(entity.Id))
        .AsEnumerable() //line not necessary if 'categories' is a local sequence
        .Join(ordering, ent => ent.Id, ord => ord.id, (ent,ord) => new {ent,ord})
        .OrderBy(x => x.ord.index)
        .Select(x => x.ent)
```

Comment: +1 because unlike my solution, this might work directly against Linq to Entities (didn't try it, but I imagine it might).

Comment: It will work because of the `AsEnumerable()` which allows you to treat the returned entities as LinqToObjects

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OrderBy` with the index of the Ids in `ids`.

To get the index of an Id from `ids`, you could create a map of Id to index.  That way you can look up the index in almost constant time, instead of having to call `IndexOf` and traverse the whole list each time.

Something like this:

```
var idToIndexMap = ids
    .Select((i, v) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
    .ToDictionary(
        pair => pair.i,
        pair => pair.v
        );

var sortedEntities = categories
    .Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id))
    .ToList() // Isn't necessary if this is Linq-to-Objects instead of entities...
    .OrderBy(e => idToIndexMap[e.Id])
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a go with this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        int[] idOrder = new int[] { 3, 2, 20, 1 };
        var lookup = idOrder.ToDictionary(i => i,
            i => Array.IndexOf(idOrder, i));
        foreach(var a in idOrder.OrderBy(i => new ByArrayComparable<int>(lookup, i)))
            Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}

public class ByArrayComparable<T> : IComparable<ByArrayComparable<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public readonly IDictionary<T, int> order;
    public readonly T element;

    public ByArrayComparable(IDictionary<T, int> order, T element)
    {
        this.order = order;
        this.element = element;
    }

    public int CompareTo(ByArrayComparable<T> other)
    {
        return this.order[this.element].CompareTo(this.order[other.element]);
    }
}
```

This works for unique elements only, but the lookup efford is constant.